# What are the steps to connect MVC core app to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been trying to connect Ms SQL server with MVC Core app using Visual Studio code.
So far I have added

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<MvcMovieContext>(options =>  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

in startup.cs file

and

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MvcMovieContext": "(Server=localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcMovieContext-20613a4b-deb5-4145-b6cc-a5fd19afda13;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "MvcMovieContext"
        }
    }
```

in appsettings.json file.

I am getting an error

> Value cannot be null.Parameter name: connectionString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appsetting.json, use connection string like this-

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

And in startup.cs, use it like this-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
}
```

For more information, refer official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core).